# Reflection in combination with marshal not working

Tags: .net, dynamic, reflection, struct, marshalling

I have a problem with reflection in combination with `MarshalAs` attributes. I would like to dynamically create structs with reflection during runtime. The structs may contain arrays which need to be marshaled. The `Field.SetMarshal()` Method is obsolete since .NET 2.0 and I'm failing to find an alternative.

Example of struct which I'm building during runtime:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack = 1)] 
public struct Example
{
    public int   var1;
    public float var2;
    public byte  var3;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public int[] var4;
}
```

Code using reflection to build structs:

```
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(pT.name,                          // Name of struct type
                                TypeAttributes.Public |           // Public scope
                                TypeAttributes.SequentialLayout | // Sequential layout
                                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass,         // Ansi Charset
                                typeof(ValueType),                // Value type
                                PackingSize.Size1);               // Packing size is 1 byte

// Add public fields to new struct type
foreach (parsedField pF in pT.fields)
{
    FieldBuilder fb = tb.DefineField(pF.name, pF.type, FieldAttributes.Public);

    // Add Marshall information to arrays
    if (fb.FieldType.IsArray)
    {
        // ADD MARSHAL INFORMATION HERE
    }
}
```

In the documentation of the obsolete UnmanagedMarshal class Microsoft says: **"Emit the MarshalAs custom attribute instead"**

Well I tried to make an `CustomAttribute` ("MarshalAs") and added it with `Field.SetCustomAttribute()` but this does not work either - the size of the struct is always wrong.

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
    public class MarshalAs : System.Attribute
    {
        public UnmanagedType type;
        public int SizeConst;

        public MarshalAs(UnmanagedType type, int SizeConst)
        {
            this.type = type;
            this.SizeConst = SizeConst;
        }
    }
```

...

```
TypeBuilder tb = mb.DefineType(pT.name,                          // Name of struct type
                                TypeAttributes.Public |           // Public scope
                                TypeAttributes.SequentialLayout | // Sequential layout
                                TypeAttributes.AnsiClass,         // Ansi Charset
                                typeof(ValueType),                // Value type
                                PackingSize.Size1);               // Packing size is 1 byte

// Add public fields to new struct type
foreach (parsedField pF in pT.fields)
{
    FieldBuilder fb = tb.DefineField(pF.name, pF.type, FieldAttributes.Public);

    // Add Marshall information to arrays
    if (fb.FieldType.IsArray)
    {
        ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(MarshalAs).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(UnmanagedType), typeof(int) });

        CustomAttributeBuilder customBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(ci, new object[] { UnmanagedType.ByValArray, 8 });

        fb.SetCustomAttribute(customBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if anyone is interested my solution solution :)

As mentioned in the documentation of the (obsolete) UnmanagedMarshal class I had to pass the "MarshalAs" attribute with a CustomAttributeBuilder.

The trick is using the MarshalAsAttribute class instead a self-written one (see code below). I had some trouble finding the solution due to the documentation on this topic is quite poor.

```
FieldBuilder fb = tb.DefineField(pF.name, pF.type, FieldAttributes.Public);

// Add Marshall information to arrays
// The "MarshallAs" attribute has to be passed with a CustomAttributeBuilder 
if (fb.FieldType.IsArray)
{
    // First we define a list of types of the arguments of the "MarshalAs" attribute constructor
    Type[] argTypes = new Type[] { typeof(UnmanagedType) };

    // Now we create a list of concrete constructor arguments for the "MarshalAs" attribute constructor
    object[] args = new object[] { UnmanagedType.ByValArray };

    // We need the field information of "SizeConst" of the MarshalAs attribute 
    FieldInfo[] sizeConstField = new FieldInfo[] { typeof(MarshalAsAttribute).GetField("SizeConst") };

    // We create the value for the field "SizeConst"
    object[] sizeConstValue = new object[] { pF.arrSize };

    // Now we retrieve the constructor of "MarshalAs" attribute that matches specified constructor argument types
    ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(MarshalAsAttribute).GetConstructor(argTypes);

    // Create builder for "MarshalAs" attribute
    CustomAttributeBuilder customBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(ci, args, sizeConstField, sizeConstValue);

    // Set builder for MarshalAs attribute                              
    fb.SetCustomAttribute(customBuilder);
}
```

Comment: The name `CustomAttributeBuilder` implies that only user-defined `Attribute` types are permitted, while the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.customattributebuilder?view=net-7.0) do mention "For example, create a `CustomAttributeBuilder` to describe an instance of `AssemblyCultureAttribute`..." In this case, `MarshalAsAttribute` is given special treatment to apply the marshaling behavior, and a user-defined attribute class won't work.